# App crashes when I use putExtra to send data and use getStringExtra to receive data?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my apps I want to pass some string data from one class to another class using intent class .I use the Following `putExtra` to send data to another class named `BusDetail` .

```
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
        {

            if(groupPosition==0)
            {
                if(childPosition == 0)
                {
                    Intent child0Intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BusDetail.class);
                    child0Intent.putExtra("ROOT",root_name[0]);
                    startActivity(child0Intent);
                }

            }

            if(groupPosition==1)
            {
                if(childPosition == 0)
                {
                    Intent child0Intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BusDetail.class);
                    child0Intent.putExtra("ROOT",root_name[0]);
                    startActivity(child0Intent);
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

The following is `BusDetail` class where I use `getStringExtra` to collect data from the above class . But my app crashes when I go to above class to following class

```
final Intent intent=getIntent();
//passedArg=in

final String id = intent.getStringExtra("ROOT");
```

Without using `putExtra` and `getStringExtra`, my app works .

this is my logcat

```
01-19 15:22:23.078  22686-22686/com.example.kuet.traveldirectory E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.kuet.traveldirectory, PID: 22686
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kuet.traveldirectory/com.example.kuet.traveldirectory.BusDetail}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.kuet.traveldirectory.BusDetail.<init>(BusDetail.java:32)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
```

Comment: What is the type of root_name?

Comment: @shurvo_kuet:  see my answer below.

Comment: also where you use `final Intent intent=getIntent();` ... and define "crash" (by posting logcat log)

Comment: Always post the logcat error trace when you talk about **Crash**, `NullPointerException`, **unfortunately app has stopped** etc. You might not know but that is the key to the solution.

Comment: post your complete code so we can help you.

Comment: `intent` is null because you don't know the Activity's lifecycle and use `getIntent()` in constructor

Comment: Please post more code of the class where you are trying to get the extras.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 what for? ... it is in a stacktrace: `BusDetail.<init>(BusDetail.java:32)` `<init>` == constructor

Comment: Error in your BusDeatil class,Post your "BusDetail" class here so we can help you.

Answer (score -1):

you should try with,

```
final String id = intent.getExtras().getString("ROOT");
```

Comment: this is not working .

Answer (score -1):

In your current Activity, create a new Intent:

```
Intent child0Intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BusDetail.class);
               child0Intent.putExtra("ROOT",root_name[0]);
                startActivity(child0Intent);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("ROOT");
}
```

Use this technique to pass variables from one Activity to the other.

Comment: post your BusDetail.java class error in that class. you might be access value in side constructor.